# Do permissions for the root folder in *nix filesystems differ from other directories?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security

In a comment under [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/989567/493903) I received a suggestion that "*permissions on the `/` folder are a special case*".

Is it true and if so, how does the implementation of permissions for the root folder differ from the permissions on other folders?

Answer (score 3):

They aren't any different. It would make very little sense to make this into some sort of special case (extra code that must be audited and tested, for a lone use case in each system, that moreover would clearly turn out a massive risk of foulups and unexpected vulnerabilities). No sane operating system architect would do this...

Answer (score 0):

No. If they were any different, it would break the concept of mounting a drive anywhere in the filesystem hierarchy.

It would introduce a necessity to take measures when mounting a drive in place of for example at `/etc`.